# HTTP Read Timeout Timer

Tags: http, timeout

When does the timer begin for a read timeout in the HTTP request/response lifecycle? Lets say I have a client with a one minute read timeout and my request contains lots of data (large binary for instance). Does that one minute timeout begin counting down the moment my client has established the socket connection to the HTTP server or does the count down begin only after the client has completed the transmission of the request containing all the data?

If it's the former then that would mean my client has a total of one minute after the initial connection has been established to begin reading the response data before a timeout occurs. If it's the latter then that means my client has a total of one minute after transmitting all data in the request to begin reading the response data before a timeout occurs.

Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: Do you expect a general answer or an answer for a specific technology stack, let's say Java, Ruby, or ...

Comment: I'm primarily interested in Java based stacks but if there are differences based on the technology stack this might be a good thread to elaborate on all of them. Doesn't seem to be very easy to find information regarding this question for any stack.